# How to listen to scroll events of a list view inside a list view in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have my widget tree as follows:

```
ListView
  - ListItem1
  - ListItem2
  - AnotherListView (shrinkWrap: true, primary: false)
```

This is working as expected and I can scroll this complete widget tree as it is a one widget. Problem arises when `AnotherListView` reaches to end of the list and I try to fetch more data from server. The scroll controller of `AnotherListView` is not firing when placed like this in parent `ListView`. It works as expected independently.

Here's my code. `StreamWidget` is returning the list view.

```
Expanded(
   child: ListView(
      children: [
         _buildPostBody(),
         const Divider(),
         PostEngagementControlsWidget(postModel: widget.postModel),
         const Divider(),
         StreamWidget(
           iStreamDataFactory: PostCommentsDataFactory(
              context: context,
              post: widget.postModel,
            ),
           iStreamWidgetFactory: PostCommentsWidgetFactory(),
           ),
         ],
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `ScrollController` and can listen to its events in `initState` like this:

```
final ScrollController winController = ScrollController();

winController.addListener(() {
      if (winController.position.pixels == winController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
          loadWin();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean I should add this controller in the parent list view? I have already defined it in the AnotherListView

Comment: Then you can create another ScrollController and attach it where you want to listen ScrollEvents. I use this method to fetch more data from the API.

Comment: As I stated in the question, I have defined a scroll controller for `AnotherListView` already. The problem is not about defining scroll controller, it is about that it is not getting triggered as AnotherListView is part of ListView, so need a solution for that.